# Quadratic fields with cyclic class group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a real quadratic field, with discriminant $d_{\mathbb{K}}<36$. Then the Minkowski's bound is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{d_{\mathbb{k}}}<3$. By the Minkowski's Theorem, each ideal class contains an ideal whose norm is $2$, at most. Considering various cases:

- $2$ is inert. In this case I've proved that the class group $\operatorname{Cl}(\mathbb{K})$ is trivial
- $2$ ramifies: $2\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{K}}=\mathfrak{p}^2$. Then $[\mathfrak{p}]^2$ is the trivial class. But which is the case? $[\mathfrak{p}]$ has period $2$ and the class group is cyclic of order $2$ or $\mathfrak{p}$ is principal and the class group is trivial?
- $2$ splits: $2\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{K}}=\mathfrak{p}_1\mathfrak{p}_2$, then $[\mathfrak{p}_1]=[\mathfrak{p}_2]^{-1}$ and the class group is generated by the class $[\mathfrak{p}_1]$. Again, can be $[\mathfrak{p}_1]$ the trivial class? It can be $[\mathfrak{p}_1]=[\mathfrak{p}_2]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class group of a real quadratic number field is generated by the non-inert prime
$\mathcal{O}_K$-ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ with $N(\mathfrak{p})<\sqrt{d_k}/2$, with $\sqrt{d_k}/2<3$ in our case. If $2$ is inert, the class number is $1$. However,
the smallest $d_K$ such that the real quadratic field with discriminant $d_k$ has class number $2$ is $d_K=40$, see  http://oeis.org/A081364.
This means that also in the other two cases, where $2$ ramifies or splits we have class number $1$.